# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet incompatible with DTO

Tags: java, hashset, classcastexception

```
public void write(List<? extends Set<DTO>> setOfDTO)
        throws Exception {

    if (!setOfDTO.isEmpty()) 
    {
        Map<BigInteger, String> tempMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>();
        for (DTO dto : setOfDTO.get(0)) {...}
```

Interesting part is, this does not happen always. So I was wondering if this has anything to do with compiler versions or some other factors. I am using Buildforge(Maven) to build these JARs

Comment: it only appears if the List has more than one item in other cases it appears always Because setOfDTO contains Set's no DTO objects

Comment: Looks like "something" passes `List<Set<Set<..>>>` around. Should be caught when using the generics correctly. Do you or a lib use raw types anywhere?

Comment: This is a spring batch program.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public void write(List<? extends Set<DTO>> setOfDTO) throws Exception {
    if (!setOfDTO.isEmpty()) {
        Map<BigInteger, String> tempMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>();
        for (Set<DTO> dto : setOfDTO) {...}
    }
}
```

Your list contains `Set<DTO>` and not `DTO` objects.

Comment: So will there be a scenario where the java line I have used will not throw an exception because as I stated above, this does not happen always.

Comment: it will always crash if your list is not empty

Comment: *"Your list contains Set<DTO> and not DTO objects."* - OP is aware of that and his `for` loop doesn't crash due to that.